# cannot Inject Named bean into javax.ws.rs class while @EJB could be used

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-rs

I try to inject a named bean into a class using `javax.ws.rs.*` and got the result of :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=UserBean,parent=NameCheckREST,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,903092946)
root cause
```

[image: error screen]

So I can guess the dependency injection failed. After I comment the `@inject` and related methods, it works. My question is why I cannot inject the named bean into javax REST class while my teacher uses `@EJB` to inject ejb and it succeeds.
Is this kind of design mechanism? You can refer to the code below:

`@inject` failed:

```
package restServices;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import beans.UserBean;

@Path("checkname")
public class NameCheckREST {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    
    @Inject
    private UserBean userBean;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public NameCheckREST() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

//    /**
//     * Retrieves representation of an instance of NameCheckREST
//     * @return an instance of String
//     */
//    @GET
//    @Produces("application/json")
//    public String getJson() {
//        // TODO return proper representation object
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
//    }
    
    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of HelloWorld
     * @return an instance of String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        // TODO return proper representation object
        //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        return "<html><body><h1>" + "Web resources for CMS"  + "</h1> </body></html>";
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of NameCheckREST
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
    
    @POST
    @Path("user")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonArray checkUsername(@FormParam("account") String account) {
        JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        JsonObjectBuilder objectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        objectBuilder.add("account", account);
        
        if(userBean.searchUserByAccount(account) == null) {         
            objectBuilder.add("exist", false);                              
        }else {
            objectBuilder.add("exist", true);           
        }       
        arrayBuilder.add(objectBuilder);
        return arrayBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

named user bean:

```
package beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import entity.NormalUser;
//import entity.User;
import repository.UserRepository;


@Named(value = "userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @EJB
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    //default constructor
    public UserBean() {
    }
    
    public List<NormalUser> getAllUsers(){
        try {
        
        List<NormalUser> users = userRepository.getAllUsers();
        //System.out.print("users:" + users.size());
        Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "users:" + users.size());
        return users;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public boolean addUser(NormalUser user) {
        try {
            userRepository.addUser(user);
            return true;
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean removeUser(String account) {
        try {
            userRepository.deleteUser(account);
            return true;
            
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean editUser(NormalUser user) {
        try {
            userRepository.updateUser(user);
            return true;
            
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            
        }
        return false;
    }   
    
    public NormalUser searchUserByAccount(String account) {
        try {
            NormalUser user = userRepository.searchUser(account);
            return user;
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

@EJB succeed:

```
package helloworld;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import calculator.LoanBean;

@Path("greeting")
public class HelloWorld {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    
    @EJB
    private NameStorageBean nameStorage;
    
    @EJB
    private LoanBean loanBean;
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of HelloWorld
     * @return an instance of String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        // TODO return proper representation object
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello " + nameStorage.getName() + ", the monthly payment is " + df.format(loanBean.calculate()) +"!</h1> </body></html>";
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void setPostName( @FormParam("name") String content) {
        nameStorage.setName(content);
    }
    
    @POST
    @Path("loan")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void setPostLoan(Loan loan) {
        loanBean.setPrinciple(loan.getPrinciple());
        loanBean.setInterestRate(loan.getInterestRate());
        loanBean.setNumberOfYears(loan.getNumberOfYears());
        loanBean.setMonthlyPayment(loanBean.calculate());
//      ELContext context
//        = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
//      WebServiceBean currentWebBean = (WebServiceBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
//                .getELResolver().getValue(context, null, "webServiceBean");
//      currentWebBean.setMonthlyPayment(loanBean.calculate());
        
    }
    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of HelloWorld
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/html")
    public void putHtml(String content) {
    }

}
```

about **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>CMS-war</display-name>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
<!--    <context-param>

    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>

    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param> -->
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>AdminContstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>WebResource</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>Administrator</description>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>NormalContstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>WebResource</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/normal/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>NormalUser</description>
            <role-name>Normal</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>cms_security</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    
    <security-role>
        <description>Administrator</description>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <description>NormalUser</description>
        <role-name>Normal</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

So is there anything I did not pay attention to or I just cannot inject named bean but ejb into javax-rest class.

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer this? Dependency injection is a big problem